# Are regular expression match group(0) & group() the same?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, grouping

```
import re

a = "AB01"
m = re.compile(r"([A-Z]{2})(\s?_?\s?)([0-9]{2})")  # note raw string
g = m.match(a)
if g:
  g = m.match(a).group(1) + "-" + m.search(a).group(3)
  print m.match(a).group()
  print m.match(a).group(0)
  print (m.match(a).group(0) == m.match(a).group())
  print g
```

In the above code, is the whole match of the group `m.match(a).group()`, is that the same as `m.match(a).group(0)`? If so, which is the preferred use?

Answer (score 2):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group):

> Without arguments, *group1* defaults to zero (the whole match is
> returned).

So, yes; `.group()` gives the same result as `.group(0)`.

---

Note that you're testing the truthiness of the compiled regex, not whether or not it has matched, which seems weird. Perhaps you meant:

```
a = "AB01"
m = re.compile(r"([A-Z]{2})(\s?_?\s?)([0-9]{2})")  # note raw string
g = m.match(a)
if g:
  ...
```

or even just:

```
...
g = re.match(r"([A-Z]{2})(\s?_?\s?)([0-9]{2})", a)
if g:
    ...
```

or ([from Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)):

```
...
if (g := re.match(r"([A-Z]{2})(\s?_?\s?)([0-9]{2})", a)):
    ...
```

as there's very little benefit to compiling in this situation.

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest note that this allows you to factor out the repeated `m.match(a)`s